# Create an image of an iphone with a mobile app splashscreen?

Tags: graphics

Quite simple really. I'm curious what programmers and developers use to promote their mobile apps on said device on a web page.

I basically am trying to recreate something like this

[image: example]
http://www.line2.com/images/01_Home.png

I doubt the guy/gal actually just starts the app on the mobile device and takes a pic of it.

Is this just photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just Photoshop, layers of images, some "clever" blending and transparency and a little too much time on their hands.

Comment: If you don;t have Photoshop (I know it's somewhat expensive), you could look at Gimp. If you wanted to be really fancy, you could use Blender to model the phone and overlay your screenshot as a texture on a 3D model. Although that's taking it a bit too far...

Comment: Ive heard of Gimp and I'm gonna give that a shot, never heard of Blender but judging by their site, seems like id have to take a class on that. I appreciate your responses.

Comment: Yeah, Blender is way overboard for what you want to do - it's the open source equivalent of Maya or 3D Studio Max. Gimp (or Gimpshop - http://www.gimpshop.com/ if you really want a Photoshop style interface) is the way to go with this.

Comment: Not a big graphics guy but Gimp seems simple enough, Im a big "trial and error" type of guy so I think eventually i should catch on and figure it out. I never used PS so the gimpshop wouldnt do me much good but thanks for the suggestion anyway.